# Mutability of lists in python

Tags: python, list, mutable

Example one: Changing the value that has been appended to b changes the value in the original list l

```
>>> l = [1 , 2, 3]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(l)
>>> b[0].append(4)
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Example 2: l1 is appended to ans and then the value of l1 is modified. However, the value in ans remains the same.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ans = []
>>> ans.append(l1)
>>> ans
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> l1 = [2, 3, 4]
>>> ans
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

I seem to be missing some fundamental point about the mutability of lists. Could someone please point it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, `l` is a pointer, as well as `b`.

`l` is then appended to b, so `b[0]` now refers to the pointer.

Next, you append 4 to `b[0]`, which is the same thing as `l`, so 4 is added to both `b[0]` *and* `l`.

---

In your second example, `ans` contains the pointer of `l1`, just like `b` contained the pointer of `l`

Then, you changed `l1` itself by assigning it to a different array, so `l1` changed but `ans[0]` did not.

---

The biggest takeaway from this is that `append` just changes the list, and the pointer remains the same. But when you set a variable to a different list, the pointer changes.

Answer (score 3):

You are not mutating `l1`. You are assigning a new object to the same name, which makes that name point to a new object. You are moving a label, not modifying an object. The only remaining reference to the list that `l1` used to point to is now `ans[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
>>> l1 = [2, 3, 4]
```

with

```
>>> l1[:] = [2, 3, 4]
```

That will not assign a new list to l1.