# Mutability of lists as it relates to the argument of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mutability

I am learning Python using Lutz's book. I am using Python 3.6.5 from Anaconda distribution. I did research this problem on SO and didn't find any thread that answers my question. [Mutability of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432396/mutability-of-lists-in-python) talks about `append` and not how we can pass a mutable object to a function.

My question is that when I make in-place changes to the list using index inside the function, the changes do get reflected, as expected because mutable objects are passed by reference. However, when I assign a list directly, the changes don't get reflected.

Specifically, I have created two lists `L1` and `L2`. For `L1`, I would do assignment using index, but for `L2`, I would do direct assignment inside the function.

```
L1=[2]
L2=['a']
print("Before, L1:",L1)
print("Before, L2:",L2)
def f(a,b):
    a[0] =[3] #Using index-based assignment
    b = ['b'] #Direct assignment

#Pass L to f
f(L1,L2)
print("After, L1:",L1)
print("After, L2:",L2)
```

The output is:

```
Before, L1: [2]
Before, L2: ['a']
After, L1: [[3]]
After, L2: ['a']
```

As we can see, `L1` got changed, but not `L2`.

**Question:** Can someone please explain why is it that the value of `L2` doesn't get changed to `'b'`?

If you believe this post is duplicate, it will be great if you tag the relevant post.

---

As an aside, I ran a small experiment to see whether there is anything to do with index-based assignment or direct assignment.

```
l=[2]
id(l)
l[0] = 3 #Index assignment
id(l) # Memory location doesn't change

l = 3 # direct assignment
id(l) #Memory location changes.
```

Hence, it seems that there is a concept I am missing, meaning I am unsure why direct assignment changes the memory location.

Comment: "because mutable objects are passed by reference." This is strictly speaking incorrect. Python *never passes by reference*, and the evaluation strategy is exactly the same for mutable types and immutable types. The fundamental misunderstanding that you have is that assignment *is not a mutation*. Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html What you call "index assignment" is actually syntactic sugar for the call `l.__setitem__(0, 3)` which is a mutator method on lists.

Comment: Thanks Juanpa. Page 524 of the book says, `Mutable objects are effectively passed "by pointer", which is similar to the way C passes arrays as pointers.` Now, I'm confused. Do you mind explaining this a bit.

Comment: It is because when you do `varname =` inside a function it sets a variable in the function scope. Not the global. So essentially you have two variables both called b inside the function if you try to print b after you set it it will print the function scope b.

Comment: Yes. That statement is correct. Note, C does not support call-by-reference as an evaluation strategy, and strictly works with call by value. Read about what call by value actually is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference). As for the evaluation strategy in Python, its [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). But seriously, all of this is pretty in the weeds. Just read and understand this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Juanpa - Thanks again for your help. I went through Wiki article you shared. The function under title "call by reference" `def modify(var p, &q) {
    p := 27 # passed by value: only the local parameter is modified
    q := 27 # passed by reference: variable used in call is modified
}`  uses direct assignment after declaring `&q` in the argument list, which is similar to what I did for the list. Isn't it? Am I missing anything?

Comment: @watchtower Yes. **Because Python does not support pass by reference**. Which is why you cannot replicate the behavior of pass by reference.

Comment: @Juanpa - Thanks again. I am a bit confused because the book, on page 524, says, `(Mutable) Objects such as Lists and Dictionaries are also passed by reference`.  Hope this topic isn't triggering debate.

Comment: @watchtower No worries, I hope I'm not coming off as contentious, but your book is simply wrong. While oftentimes people are sloppy with the terminology and use "pass-by-reference" incorrectly, the book is definitely wrong in implying that there are different evaluation strategies for mutable and immutable objects. Like I stated, Python has only one evaluation strategy for argument passing, and it works *exactly the same* for mutable and immutable objects, immutable objects simply lack methods to mutate them. Again, *read and understand this* https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: That's a good reference. Thanks for sharing. Here's another one I found: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we change your code slightly, we can use `id` to see how the references change (or don't change):

```
L1=[2]
L2=['a']
print("Before, L1:", L1, id(L1))
print("Before, L2:", L2, id(L2))
def f(a,b):
    print("Inside, Before, a:", id(a))
    print("Inside, Before, b:", id(b))
    a[0] =[3] #Using index-based assignment
    b = ['b'] #Direct assignment
    print("Inside, After, a:", id(a))
    print("Inside, After, b:", id(b))

#Pass L to f
f(L1,L2)
print("After, L1:", L1, id(L1))
print("After, L2:", L2, id(L2))
```

**Output:**

```
Before, L1: [2]     1870498294152  # L1
Before, L2: ['a']   1870498294280  # L2
Inside, Before, a:  1870498294152  # L1
Inside, Before, b:  1870498294280  # L2
Inside, After, a:   1870498294152  # L1
Inside, After, b:   1870498239496  # Something different, not L2
After, L1: [[3]]    1870498294152  # L1
After, L2: ['a']    1870498294280  # L2
```

Note, the numbers aren't significant in themselves other than to help distinguish references to different objects.  Running this yourself (or if I ran it again), would cause the ids to change.

With `a`, you're modifying/mutating `a` but not attempting to re-assign the reference.  That's fine.

With `b`, you're re-assigning the reference.  This will work *inside* the function (as the "Inside, After, b:" print call shows), but this change *will not* be reflected outside of the function.  `b` will be restored to reference the original object, `['a']`.

**As to *why*...**

> meaning I am unsure why direct assignment changes the memory location.

Inside your function, `a` and `b` are just references to objects.  Initially, they reference (the objects referenced by) `L1` and `L2` respectively because by calling `f`, you're passing references to those objects.

`a[0] = [3]` first dereferences `a` (or `L1` in this case), then the `[0]` index, and sets that value.

In fact, if you look at `id(a[0])` before and after that call then *that* would change.  `a` is a list of references.  Try it:

```
print(id(a[0]))   # One thing
a[0] =[3] #Using index-based assignment
print(id(a[0]))   # Something different
```

This is fine.  When you exit the function `L1` will still reference the object that the function references using `a` and it's mutation at the 0-index will remain.

With `b = ['b']` you're reassigning or rebinding `b` to a new object.  The old object still exists (for later use outside the function).

Lastly, I use the term "reference" a lot, but Python is not precisely a "pass-by-reference" language, [rather variable names are bound to objects](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/).  In the second, you're rebinding `b`, losing the association to the originally-referenced object `L2` forever.

Comment: For others who are reading, here's a good reference on above discussion https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/ . Another good link is https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html